# Stripes in TPI from SRTM 30 DEM

Tags: google-earth-engine, elevation, tpi

The TPI is calculated with a 150 to 300m annulus in Google Earth Engine.
The underlying Elevation-Data from SRTM does not show such striped.
I did use raw SRTM from GEE for elevation, no reprojecting or resampling

Unfortunatly i cannot share the whole code, the TPI is not depicted well with `Map.addLayer()`
 The depicted example is an asset export with a Landsat 5 projection from central europe. The image is from Switzerland.

My TPI Function

`var TPI = function(elevation, inner, outer){
  var inner = ee.Number(inner)
  var outer = ee.Number(outer)
  var kernelo = ee.Kernel.circle(outer,'meters',false,1)
  var kerneli = ee.Kernel.circle(inner,'meters',false,-1)
  var kernel = kernelo.add(kerneli)//created annulus
  var focalmean = elevation.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), kernel)
  var name = ee.String('TPI').cat(ee.String(inner)).cat('_').cat(ee.String(outer))
  var TPI = elevation.subtract(focalmean).regexpRename('elevation',name)
  return TPI
}`

[image]

are the stripes fixable with some reprojecting? My best Gues: the TPI algorithm highlights the Data pattern from Sensorcollection. Thus all stripes are aligned,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Original answer remains below. Your diagonal striping is an artifact in the SRTM elevation raster, it's a common issue. The value differences in the DEM are subtle but they become apparent in extremely flat areas or in elevation-derived rasters like TPI. You could try using the ALOS DEM, which is also available through GEE, or depending on your application you could do a 1-pixel median filter (that's a focal_median reducer in EE) which should clean up at least some of the banding at the expense of losing a little bit of detail.

---

Your TPI is going to be a single-band image (or a single band within a multi-band export). Therefore it is unlikely that your yellow stripes are part of the same raster (or raster band), which is rendered in a black-to-white color ramp. They have to be from another layer, which is why they are overlaid with some transparency on the TPI raster in your included image.

Comment: The yellow marked areas indicate the stripe location

Comment: I see that now, but it should be clearer in your question. The stripes are an artifact of SRTM data collection, as you suspect. It's a well-known issue, usually too subtle to notice in hilly areas but often detectable where the terrain is very flat. Your TPI calculation is making them more visible.